# django did not use his localization file

Tags: django, localization, internationalization

Have this code in my settings.py file:

```
LANGUAGES = (
  ('ru', 'Russian'),
)
DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 0
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-RU'
```

but error:

```
raise forms.ValidationError(_("Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields are case-sensitive."))
```

return message in english language, although that django has translation in django /usr/local/lib/python-2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/django.po

Why ?

Here is MIDDLWARE:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    # 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    # 'cms.middleware.multilingual.MultilingualURLMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware',
    'banner_middleware.Banner',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'cms.context_processors.media',
    'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ensure `USE_I18N = True` in settings
2. use same code, `'ru'`, for `LANGUAGE_CODE` and the key of the first item in `LANGUAGES`
3. ensure the `Accept-Language` in your request header take `'ru'` with higher priority.
4. As mega.venik's suggestion, ensure there is translation for the string in po and mo files in findable locale directory.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - are you sure, that `LANGUAGE` setting also covers error messages?

Sencond - check the correctness of the `LANGUAGE_CODE` value. According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/#term-language-code), it should be in lower case

By the way, try to add `'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'`to the `settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.